# Undefined property: App\\Domains\\Import\\Listeners\\ImportEventListeners::$guzzleClient"

Tags: laravel, service-provider

My service provider has below code:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Domains\Import\Listeners\ImportEventListeners; 
use GuzzleHttp\Client as GuzzleClient;

class GuzzleServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        Event::subscribe(ImportEventListeners::class);
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->app->bind('GuzzleHttp\Client', function () {
            return new GuzzleClient;
        });
    }
}
```

I want to use Guzzle service in my listener but it's giving error

```
    <?php
namespace App\Domains\Import\Listeners;

use GuzzleHttp\Client as GuzzleClient;


class ImportEventListeners implements ShouldQueue
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function handle(Event $event, GuzzleClient $guzzleClient)
    {
        $this->guzzleClient = $guzzleClient;
        dd($this->guzzleClient);
    }
}
```

Comment: fyi, Laravel has [http-client](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client) already

Comment: @brombeer not clear to me. Could you please explain little bit more?

Comment: There's no class property `guzzleClient` in the class `ImportEventListeners`. `$this->guzzleClient` does not exist is what the message is telling you

Comment: Remove `$this->guzzleClient = $guzzleClient;` and use `dd($guzzleClient);`

Comment: even if I define property, I am not getting service provider object in listener